# Is it possible to recalculate all cells (i.e. Ctrl+Shift+F9 function) automatically on a timer?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have written functions that access off-sheet data that is prone to changing regularly. Pressing Ctrl+Shift+F9 refreshes these cells, while F9 alone does not. Is there a way to automate refreshing this data - say, once a minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running libreoffice 4.4.3.2
Ok you can use a link to a value in another sheet if you like.
To create a name range insert->names->define

```
Sub recalc_timer
 document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
  switch_on = ThisComponent.NamedRanges("switched_on").ReferredCells.getCellByPosition(0,0)
 dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

 rem value must be more than 0 to hold while condition

 while switch_on.getValue()>0

 dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:CalculateHard", "", 0,   Array())
 rem wait time in milliseconds
 wait 3000
 wend
End Sub
```

*proviso

Important: Some functions may not be updated. Please test https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Recalculate